# How high can Spider-man jump?

Tags: spider-man, marvel

In an answer about [Spidey vs. Doc Ock](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/78620/31178), we learned that Spider-man is actually one of the stronger Marvel super-heroes. It's also often stated that he has the proportional strength of a spider, but that amount tends to vary by writer/spider.

However, since he's so strong, I wonder how high he can leap. Can he leap tall buildings in a single bound? Short buildings? Just buses?

An exact value isn't necessary if it's not available; an inference based on examples, physics(!), or in-universe comments is fine.

Comment: He has jumped to moon if my memories aren't misleading me.

Answer (score 6):

In his first appearance, Spider-Man was shown jumping about 3 stories, or roughly 36 feet, according to Spider-Man: The Ultimate Guide. (The wikipedia entry only states "several stories") I believe the 3 story mark is as high as he has been SHOWN to leap in any medium.

Presumably, he COULD leap higher, but much beyond that, he just prefers to rely on his weblines instead.

Comment: In the *Spider-Man 2* film tie-in videogame, Spider-Man could jump much higher than three stories.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take the [Jumping Spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_spider)

> Most jumping spiders can jump several times the length of their bodies<sup>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_spider#Behavior)</sup>

Extrapolating, say [Spiderman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man) is six feet tall. and lets say 25<sup>[source](http://www.answers.com/Q/How_HIGH_can_the_best_jumping_spider_jump_How_FAR_can_the_best_jumping_spider_jump)</sup> times his height that make it about 150 *feet*.
He'll clear a small building for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Given the elasticity of his joints without tearing and his physical strength, if he can press at least 10 tons of weight with his arms, he can probably leg press 20-30 tons with his legs. In 2016, Evan Ungar from Canada set the highest vertical jump Guinness World Record at 63.5 inches (over 5 feet from standing). I'm guessing with his strength he can kickoff and jump over 3-5 stories.